# Contatenation with grunt-contrib-concat doesn't work

Tags: gruntjs

I use grunt-contrib-concat, but it doesn't appear to work.
All file are in the folder.

I used `--verbose` to see the details, but everything seems to be working correctly.

```
 concat: {
   options: {
    // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
    separator: ';'
  },
   dist: {
      // the files to concatenate
      src: [
          //'assets/javascript/components/*.js',
          'assets/javascript/components/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js',
          'assets/javascript/components/spectrum.js',
          'assets/javascript/components/prefixfree.min.js',
         'assets/javascript/src/jquery.menu_css3.js'
      ],
      // the location of the resulting JS file
      dest: 'assets/javascript/jquery.<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
    }
  },
```

Running the tasks with `--verbose`:

```
Running "concat" task

Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
Verifying property concat.dist exists in config...OK
Files: assets/javascript/src/jquery.menu_css3.js ->         assets/javascript/jquery.menu_css3.min.js
Options: separator=";", banner="", footer="", stripBanners=false, process=false
Reading assets/javascript/src/jquery.menu_css3.js...OK
Writing assets/javascript/jquery.menu_css3.min.js...OK
File "assets/javascript/jquery.menu_css3.min.js" created.

Running "uglify" task

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.dist exists in config...OK
Files: assets/javascript/jquery.menu_css3.min.js ->         assets/javascript/jquery.menu_css3.min.js
Options: banner="", footer="", compress={"warnings":false}, mangle={}, beautify=false,     report=false
Minifying with UglifyJS...Reading assets/javascript/jquery.menu_css3.min.js...OK
OK
Writing assets/javascript/jquery.menu_css3.min.js...OK
File "assets/javascript/jquery.menu_css3.min.js" created.
```

Comment: What are the contents of the `dest` files after you run the task?

Comment: this file: jquery.menu_css3.js to jquery.menu_css3.min.js.
But nothing else, it is compress with uglyfly.

Comment: I put all file in src and that works well.